# PHP Error in MySQL Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, function, syntax

Here's the function I created:

```
function get_phurl_option($option) {
$db_result  =   mysql_query("SELECT value FROM ".DB_PREFIX."options WHERE option = '$option'") or db_die(__FILE__, __LINE__, mysql_error());
$db_row     =   mysql_fetch_row($db_result);
return $db_row[0];
}
```

However, upon visiting a page that uses the function, I get the following error:

```
File: /usr/home/<removed>/includes/functions.php
Line: 28
Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option = 'shortcode_type'' at line 1
```

I'm not sure why this would be, I've tried apostrophes, speech marks, and backticks, neither of which seem to work. I can't figure out the problem here, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Escape your variables correctly, it will save you lots of errors and nerves.

Comment: What does $option look like? The query itself looks fine, assuming DB_PREFIX is set

Comment: Echo out the final query before executing it... That will allow you to see exactly where the problem is...

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

option is a MySQL reserved word, so you need to enclose it in backticks

```
$db_result  =   mysql_query("SELECT value FROM ".DB_PREFIX."options WHERE `option` = '$option'")
```

Answer (score 1):

The specified error usually means that the field you're attempting to access is invalid or reserved by MySQL. Make sure you escape all variables in backticks:

```
SELECT `value` FROM `".DB_PREFIX."options` WHERE `option` = '$option'
```